# Having trouble saving a plot with legends

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to plot a graph.

```
Subscript[R, 0] = 1.2; 
Subscript[A, Pb] = 208 ; 
Subscript[A, Ca] = 40; 
Subscript[A, O] = 16; 
Subscript[ρ, 0] = 0.138;
R[A_] := Subscript[R, 0]*(A^(1/3))
ρ[r_, R_, a_] := Subscript[ρ, 0]/(1 + Exp[(r - R)/a])
```

I cannot save the following plot with its legend.

```
a = 0.5;
Plot[{
  ρ[r, R[Subscript[A, Pb]], a], 
  ρ[r, R[Subscript[A, Ca]], a], 
  ρ[r, R[Subscript[A, O]], a]}, 
  {r, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r (fm)", "ρ(r) nucleons/fm\.b3"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Pb", "Ca", "O"}, Right]]
```

I cannot select both the plot and legends to save them. How can I deal with this?

Comment: To get a contextual menu allowing you to save the entire contents of a cell, right-click the **cell bracket** on the right of the output. Then choose `Save Selection As...` In your case, this will save the graphic and legend together.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: @m_goldberg How did you typed the greek letter rho in?

Comment: I used halirutan's [plug-in](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/3066)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your plot (let us say p) and the export it.

```
a = 0.5;
p=Plot[{\[Rho][r, R[Subscript[A, Pb]], a], \[Rho][r, 
R[Subscript[A, Ca]], a], \[Rho][r, R[Subscript[A, O]], a]}, {r, 0, 
10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"r (fm)", "\[Rho](r) nucleons/fm\.b3"}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Pb", "Ca", "O"}, Right]]
```

and then export it using export command

```
Export["plot.jpg", p]
```

you will find the picture in the default folder which is normally Documents.

[image]